# MySQL return values when no rows found

Tags: mysql

I want to return a MySQL result set even when no rows are found that simulates the correct result set with default values.

This is so I don't have to have any logic in my display of this data... I can just push it out.

What I would like to do is always return 3 Warehouses... 000 CAL RET   with values of 0 when nothing is found.

If a new warehouse is ever added I would hopefully be able to modify this to include that warehouse also.

Here goes:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e94bc

I would want to return another row for RET warehouse with zeros in all columns.

If you query another ItemCode that doesn't exist, I want to see all 3 rows 000 CAL RET with zero values in each column.

as a bonus I would also like to always return 0 and not (NULL) as a value.

I have searched for answers, but can't seem to find exactly what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle is broken (Please build schema.)

Comment: I think I fixed it. The fiddle I mean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168676/mysql-return-default-value-if-no-rows-returned Hope this post helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a master table of your warehouses with 0 in every column.

```
CREATE TABLE ItemWarehouseMaster
    (`Warehouse` varchar(3), `QOH` int, `QPO` int, `QSO` int, `QBO` int,`ItemCode` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO ItemWarehouseMaster
    (`Warehouse`, `QOH`, `QPO`, `QSO`, `QBO`, `ItemCode`)

    ('CAL', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    ('RET', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    ('000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
```

then your query can join on this table and perform a coalesce on the 2 sets of data, for each column you should have a 0 from the mastertable and the value from your database, if the value from your database is null it will take the 0 from the 'master' table.

```
SELECT
    w.Warehouse,
    coalesce (w.QOH,Mast.QOH),
    coalesce (w.QSO,Mast.QSO),
    coalesce (w.QPO,Mast.QPO),
    coalesce (w.QBO,Mast.QBO)
FROM
    ItemWarehouseMaster Mast
left join
     ItemWarehouse w on
w.warehouse = mast.warehouse

And w.itemcode = '10052IP'
```

Comment: Actually this seems so close to working, but when I query it with an item code that doesn't exist I don't get any values.   Also it does not fill in the empty rows from what I can tell.

Comment: Ah, the where should be part of the join instead so it only joins on those records that match the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT querytype, col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM (SELECT 1 AS querytype, col1, col2, col3, ...
      FROM YourTable
      WHERE ...
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS querytype, 0, 0, 0, ...
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS querytype, 0, 0, 0, ...
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS querytype, 0, 0, 0, ...) AS x
HAVING querytype = MIN(querytype)
```

Everything before the first `UNION ALL` is your regular query, but with the added `querytype` column. If that query returns anything, `MIN(querytype)` will be `1`, and those rows will match the `HAVING` clause. Otherwise, `MIN(querytype)` will be `2`, and the default rows will match.

Comment: You have a tiny error in your query, It should be `SELECT querytype, col1, col2, col3, ...`. Otherwise, querytype won't be found.

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the same situation, and I could manage to return values in a similar way as Barmar describes, slightly more simple though.

```
SELECT mycol FROM (
  SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE condcol = 'some value' 
  UNION SELECT 'hardcoded value'
) alias
LIMIT 1;
```

If the first query doesn't return any row, the second will always return the hard coded value. If you need to return more hard coded rows, just add `UNION SELECT 'another value'` as many times as you need.
The `LIMIT` statement at the end lets you make sure that you wouldn't return the hard-coded rows if you find real rows.

Note that your original query would become a derived query and it must have an alias. Otherwise, you will see this error:
`Error in query (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias`.
I hope this helps!