# MySql, return default value if no rows returned

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query as below

```
SELECT cap_id FROM cap_master WHERE   
        (cap_type = 'Type1' AND cap_desc = 'CapDesc1') 
     OR (cap_type = 'Type2' AND cap_desc = 'CapDesc2')
     OR (cap_type = 'Type3' AND cap_desc = 'CapDesc3')
     OR (cap_type = 'Type4' AND cap_desc = 'CapDesc4')
order by cap_type,cap_desc
```

This returns multiple rows based on **where** condition, what i am looking for is like for a condition which do not return any rows, i should have a default value say '0'. As of now i do not get any row for it.

For e.g if 3rd condition (*cap_type = 'Type3' AND cap_desc = 'CapDesc3'*) do not match, i am expecting an output as below:

```
23
34
0  
45
```

I checked solutions given, like

[Return a value if no rows match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000017/return-a-value-if-no-rows-match)

[Return Default value if no row found -mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558295/return-default-value-if-no-row-found-mysql)

But seems they don't work on multiple rows getting returned. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b9bb0/2) to play with.

Comment: It would help if you posted sample data and expected results, ideally as a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: If you have a reference table with all the possible types, then you could perform a `OUTER JOIN` by `cap_type`. So you would know _which_ type is missing

Comment: Added the fiddle in Question asked.

Comment: Is there another table containing all possible types? @pranav

Comment: No, we don't have, this is the actually a master table.

Comment: Where do these different types come from, that you use in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Basically i get them in Json response, i use them to query the DB to get the IDs. From that list, I have know what matched what not (If i get a query which works for the situation, i can know all in one shot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join`:

```
select coalesce(cm.cap_id, 0) as cap_id
from (select 'Type1' as cap_type, 'CapDesc1' as cap_desc union all
      select 'Type2' as cap_type, 'CapDesc2' as cap_desc union all
      select 'Type3' as cap_type, 'CapDesc3' as cap_desc union all
      select 'Type4' as cap_type, 'CapDesc4' as cap_desc
     ) c left join
     cap_master cm
     on cm.cap_type = c.cap_type and cm.cap_desc = c.cap_desc
order by c.cap_type, c.cap_desc;
```

If you need to support `NULL` `cap_desc` (which is not part of the original question), you can do:

```
select coalesce(cm.cap_id, 0) as cap_id
from (
      select 'Type5' as cap_type, null as cap_desc
     ) c left join
     cap_master cm
     on cm.cap_type = c.cap_type and 
        (cm.cap_desc = c.cap_desc or cm.cap_desc is null and c.cap_desc is null)
order by c.cap_type, c.cap_desc;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa74be/6) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I tried similar to this, but this wont maintain the order. Can check with Fiddle provided. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b9bb0/2

Comment: I added a solution which seems to work fine. If it would hurt efficiency, a better and efficient solution is always welcome :)

Comment: @pranav . . . This query appears to do exactly what you ask for:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8661c7/1.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, now it works. So we have 2 ways to do now. I tried with IFNULL, which worked fine too.This is concise, will use this.

Comment: It gives: 'Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' ' in my database.  People who face this can fix as given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008287/illegal-mix-of-collations-mysql-error

Comment: seems the join won't help if any column is null, or am i doing it wrong: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa74be/1

Comment: @pranav . . . I added the logic to fix that problem.

Comment: Thanks again Gordon !!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use IFNULL to do what you want. It is untested since you didn't provide a minimal set of data to run the query on:

```
SELECT IFNULL( (SELECT cap_id FROM cap_master WHERE   
        (cap_type = 'Type1' AND cap_desc = 'CapDesc1`) 
     OR (cap_type = 'Type2' AND cap_desc = 'CapDesc2')
     OR (cap_type = 'Type3' AND cap_desc = 'CapDesc3')
     OR (cap_type = 'Type4' AND cap_desc = 'CapDesc4')
order by cap_type,cap_desc) ,'0');
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) you can find some more detail on IFNULL

Comment: Wouldn't this return `0` only, if there is _no_ data with _Type1_, _Type2_, _Type3_ AND _Type4_? He wants the `0` only if a specific Type is missing (for that result row)

Comment: no, it should do its job (but I didn't test it with OP's data). The only other option if this doesn't work is to split the query into 4 subqueries

Comment: it would but it is the most unefficient way to do it

Comment: Tried using IFNULL as this, it seems it wont work on multiple rows. Gives 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'.

Comment: So I tried your query. Either it returns an error, because there is more than one row coming back or it's like I said - it only works, when there is no data fullfilling any of the conditions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2a4a4/1/0

Answer (score 1):

A solution which i was able to figure out. Not sure if this hurts efficiency much, i guess at a time i will have 20 conditions max. Let me know if there's some alternative.

```
SELECT ifnull((SELECT cap_id FROM cap_master WHERE cap_type = 'Type4' AND 
cap_desc = 'CapDesc4' ),0) as cap_id
union all
SELECT ifnull((SELECT cap_id FROM cap_master WHERE cap_type = 'Type7' AND 
cap_desc = 'CapDesc7' ),0) as cap_id
union all
SELECT ifnull((SELECT cap_id FROM cap_master WHERE cap_type = 'Type3' AND 
cap_desc = 'CapDesc3' ),0) as cap_id
union all
SELECT ifnull((SELECT cap_id FROM cap_master WHERE cap_type = 'Type6' AND 
cap_desc = 'CapDesc6' ),0) as cap_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try CASE function :) You can assign what and where should be shown

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Comment: `CASE` would not help here

Comment: i think CASE would be helpful where we get a row. Here it's like there is no row returned to write a case on it.